# Regarding radiobutton count and then change class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is markup of html

```
<input type="checkbox" title="enable" value="30"/>
<input type="checkbox" title="enable" value="31"/>
<input type="checkbox" title="disable" value="32"/>
<input type="checkbox" title="disable" value="33"/>
<input type="checkbox" title="disable" value="34"/>
<a class="testdisable" id="testhere">TESTCLASS</a>
```

Now I want disable class to be applied if any one of the checkbox selected is disable.If two enable checkbox are selected then I want disable class to be applied on anchor.and if two disable checkbox are selected then I want enable  class to be applied on anchor tag.
I tried below jquery code..but not getting proper result..I am getting problem on two disable and two disable and one enable

MY JS FIDDLE :-http://jsfiddle.net/TpBGG/1/

Comment: In the first case which element should get the disabled class

Comment: firstly anchor tag will be in disabled mode i mean it will disable class

Comment: ok let me explain my requirement again..If a checkbox has title=enable and if it is checked.then I want to apply class disable to anchor tag.Now if few checkbox are selected and any one of them has title=disable then I want class to be applied as disable on anchor.and if amongst few of checkbox are selected if all of them are having title=disable then i want to apply class enable on anchor tag..Hope it is clear now...raju bhai is sitting besides me..so i am explaining its requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try this

```
function changeclass() { if ($('input:checked[title="disable"]').length >= 1 && $('input:checked[title="enable"]').length >= 1) { $('a[name=enable_anchor]').attr('class', 'testdisable'); } else if ($('input:checked[title="enable"]').length >= 1) { $('a[name=enable_anchor]').attr('class', 'testdisable'); } else if ($('input:checked[title="disable"]').length >= 1) { $('a[name=enable_anchor]').attr('class', 'testenable'); } //else { // $('a[name=enable_anchor]').attr('class', 'testdisable'); //} }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
    function changeclass() {
alert('before' + $('#testhere').attr('class'));
if ($('input:checked[title="disable"]').length == 1) {
    $('#testhere').attr('class', 'disable');
}
else if (($('input:checked[title="disable"]').length > 1) && ($('input:checked[title="enable"]').length == 1))
{
    $('#testhere').attr('class', 'disable');
}
else if ($('input:checked[title="enable"]').length > 1) {
    $('#testhere').attr('class', 'disable');
}
else {
    $('#testhere').attr('class', 'enable');
}
alert('after' + $('#testhere').attr('class'));}
```

Comment: ok this is working much better for him..but when i select two disable title checkbox--> and then select one enable title checkbox ..then it is coming enable instead of disable could u please fix that..??